# Web Workers - How to achieve exception Handling for importScripts()

Tags: javascript, html, exception, web-worker

I'm using `importScripts()` in my dedicated Worker to get data from Facebook API using Graph. Occasionally the request appears to time out and Chrome Dev Tools just show a red GET and print the URL that failed to be retrieved.

I tried wrapping the `importScripts()` in a try/catch block but that didn't seem to help much.

Can that error be handled via proper exception handling? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is browser dependent what happens if that fails, the [Mozilla dev documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) says:

```
The browser loads each listed script and executes it.
Any global objects from each script may then be used by the worker.
If the script can't be loaded, NETWORK_ERROR is thrown, and subsequent
code will not be executed.
```

Why Chrome does not do the same I think might be a question for the Chrome/Chromium bugtacker.
Start with their mailing lists...

Answer (score 0):

I came hunting for answers to this - what I got was this:

```
try { 
    importScripts('somebadPath.js') 
} catch(e) { 
    // dosomethingwith(e.message || e.code || e.name); 
}
```

Works fine for me in Chrome, both today's Canary and this week's Chrome, Mac (27 aug 13). Maybe it's older versions you need to be worried about? And in that case, you probably don't need to be worried too much?